# Holonomy of a flat connection around a contractible loop

Tags: differential-geometry, connections, flatness, holonomy

I'm currently reading a paper written by John Baez [1]. At a certain point he argues, that the holonomy of a *flat connection* around a *contractible loop* is the identity, so its trace in the representation $ρ$ is dim($ρ$).

More explicit, 
$$
\operatorname{tr}\left(\rho\left(T e^{\oint_{e} A}\right)\right)\stackrel{A\, \text{is flat}}{=}\text{dim}{(\rho)}\,.
$$

What I don't see is the exact proof for 
$$
e^{\oint_{e} A} =1 \;\;,\text { by flatness }
$$

I imagine that it could be done with Stokes theorem, but I'm not sure...

---

[1] An Introduction to Spin Foam Models of BF Theory and Quantum Gravity.   [https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9905087v1.pdf]

Comment: What definition of flatness are you using? The triviality of holonomy around contractible loops is sometimes takes as the definition of flat.

Comment: @Kajelad  flat w.r.t. curvature.

Comment: It's hard to know what you know. This is a simple case of the Ambrose-Singer Theorem.